# Open Execute Anonymous Window is disabled. How can I Enable it.

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to salesforce. I had logged in on the salesforce. I got developer console in my settings. When I tapped Ctrl+e it shows "You don't have permission to execute apex". Please help to enable these features.
[image: This is the dialogue box i got when i tapped ctrl+e]

Answer (score 1):

You have to check user license and which salesforce edition you are using.

If you are using Professional Edition, you can't use APEX unless it's from a managed package.

edit: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96501/setting-permission-to-write-apex-classes